# How to handle a long sequential composition in Scala Parser Combinators?

Tags: scala, parsing, parser-combinators

How can I process a sequential composition such as

```
(String, String) ~ (String, String) ~ (String, String) ~ (String, String) ~ (String, String) ~ (String, String) ~ (String, String) ~ (String, String) ~ (String, String) ~ (String, String) ~ (String, String) ~ (String, String) ~ (String, String) ~ (String, String) ~ (String, String)?
```

Normally I would handle it as

```
def member: Parser[(String, Any)] =
stringLiteral~":"~value ˆˆ
{ case name~":"~value => (name, value) }
```

How to handle a long sequential composition?

My goal is to create a Map of all (String, String) pairs.

If I try to do it similar way then it would look as

```
 ^^ {
 case (str1, str2) ~ (str3, str4) ~ (str5, str6).... => {
    // Add all (k,v) into a Map[String, String]
 }
}
```

Comment: I think you are looking for the `rep` parser, or `repN` if there is a fixed number of elements. Then just `to(Map)` on the resulting `List[(String, Any))`. If there is a conjunction between each element use `chainl1`. But please don't use `Any`, use a more specific type for the values that might actually be generated.

Comment: The problem with rep is it will give me all combinations and I want to process them sequentially.

Comment: `rep` will give you a `List` of all the matching elements that you can process sequentially, so not sure what the problem is with that. You might need to show a bit more of the code you are using to explain what the problem is. What processing can't you do using `rep`?